How to proxy / tunnel a chrome devtools websocket?
I have a very odd environment that I need to debug. Essentially, I'm in a situation where a puppeteer based webcrawler is failing to work only when it is deployed on a server in a docker container. When I try to reproduce it locally, even in docker, it works correctly. It is only when deployed that it fails.
Having exhausted all other options, I need a way of debugging the deployed container's chrome browser. My only way of connecting to it is to get a shell via Skuba (a kubernetes CLI tool). It otherwise isn't publicly reachable (i.e I cannot ping its IP).
Puppeteer opens up a devtools websocket on localhost that's meant for debugging. This is what I want access to. This'll let me see network requests, console, etc to see why the crawl is failing.
However, since the container isn't publicly addressed, I can't just plug ws://<server_ip>:46705/devtools/browser/<id> into my local chrome browser. However, due to the fact that it is a webcrawler, it can make requests out to the internet.
What I would like to do is stand up a publicly reachable server (publicserver.com), have the troublesome container connect to it and forward its websocket locally via ws://publicserver.com:46705/devtools/browser/<id>
I've done something similar before with a reverse ssh tunnel, but I'm unsure how to get this working with websockets. How can I achieve this?
I realize that this is a very weird thing to do, but this is truly the best option I have; this is the only environment I can reproduce this bug in and it's unfortunately the environment I have to deploy to.
